# How to set up intent for viewing Bitmap with default Android image viewer?

Tags: android, android-image

What I am trying to do is to download image from web and show it on screen with zoom/pan capability. I've successfully downloaded image into Bitmap instance, but ImageView doesnt have zooming feature. 
So instead I'm willing to present it with default viewer which has zoom/pan features.

How do I set up Intent to view Bitmap with default Android image viewer?
I know Intents action should be View:

```
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

But how to provide data for Intent when image is in Bitmap instance *myBitmap*?

Comment: I've Googled for showing zoomable images, but only found decent difficulty code only for Android 2.1 and higher. Though I also want this to work in Android 1.6

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Android default image viewer use below code

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("string Uri")));
```

or if you want to show Imageview with zoom In/Out functionality refer below question
[Android Multi touch zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977138/android-multi-touch-zooming/5977592#5977592)

Comment: It would help if you could show me how to build *"string Uri"* from Bitmap instance *myBitmap*. I've came up to this point myself and stuck. Should I save that Bitmap to file and then parse Uri from file or can I somehow give Bitmap instance directly (dont need to save it).

Comment: Uri can not be created from instance of Bitmap, it can only be created from saved location in that case you have to implement your own zoomable ImageView as given in the link

Comment: As mentioned, I want it to be zoomable in 1.6 too and that Multitouch code is at least for 2.1. But thanks for clearing it out, that URI can be created only from saved file. Will try to do that.