# Application crashes during runtime in android?

Tags: android, zooming

I am making a small application in android to zoom an image but the application crashes at runtime. Here is the code:

```
package new1.zoom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;


    public class newzoom extends View {
        private Drawable image;
        private int zoomControler=200;
        public newzoom(Context context)
        {
        super(context);
        image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.me);
        setFocusable(true);
        }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //here u can control the width and height of the images........ this line is very important
    image.setBounds((getWidth()/2)-zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)-zoomControler, (getWidth()/2)+zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)+zoomControler);
    image.draw(canvas);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP)// zoom in
    zoomControler+=10;
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) // zoom out
    zoomControler-=10;
    if(zoomControler<10)
    zoomControler=10;
    invalidate();
    return true;
    }
    }
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Here is my logcat file:

```
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{new1.zoom/new1.zoom.newzoom}: java.lang.InstantiationException: new1.zoom.newzoom
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: new1.zoom.newzoom
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
06-14 11:30:14.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(985):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Did you try to debug? What's the exception thrown (look at logcat at eclipse).

Comment: I have placed the log cat file in the question above. thanks

Comment: this is connected to the instance creation. how do you create an instance of this class? what is your activity code. this looks fine. maybe onDraw is a bit suspicious. try without that maybe just as a check.

Comment: can you give me any other solution to zoom an image in the application

Answer (score 0):

please go through the given link. It uses multi touch and tap to zoom the image: [Android Multi touch zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977138/android-multi-touch-zooming). In that there a link: http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/ It worked for me. Please try this also.