# Image loses quality in WebView

Tags: android, image, webview

I'm displaying a 1500x1000 px sized image in an Android WebView, but it displays it in poor quality. I read somewhere that quality can be preserved using and displaying many smaller parts from the original image, but that seems like too much work and not sure how it really could work.

I added

```
<supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

and created a drawable-hdpi folder and put the image in there, with no change.
Has anyone done this succesfully or any suggestions?

Comment: WHy you want to use web view not Image view?

Comment: I could not find a way to zoom in a ImageView, and many people suggest to use WebView instead.

Comment: Check following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977138/android-multi-touch-zooming/5977592#5977592